# How to Group By and then toMap streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of objects on which i want to group by 2 columns and then use toMap to collect all the values.

Let us say I have an Object with 5 attributes. of Class A (a,b,c,d,e) and a list of those objects say list. what i wanted to achieve is group by a, b and create a map with key as c and all the objects including it.

```
//Expected format of output map:
Map<a, Map<b, Map<c, List<A>> myMap = new HashMap<>();


myMap = list.stream().
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::a,
     Collectors.groupingBy(A::b,
     Collectors.toMap(A::c, Collectors.toList()))); //-> Here i'm expecting the map's key will be C and values should be all the onces which are grouped by a & b.
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to group by `(a, b)` and yet have `c` as the key of the map... Can you maybe add example data?

Comment: Yes it might not add a value, but i have got an usecase where i ended up in forming the map that way in order to send it to some other expecting service.

Comment: can you show an example with input data to output data @SantoshKsl

Comment: @SantoshKsl have you tried `.collect(groupingBy(A::getA, groupingBy(A::getB, groupingBy(A::getC))))` ?

Comment: input data is flat object. 
Assuming in object a = product, b = date, c = name. And I have a separate config like identical names config which says for example , name1 can be equivalent to { name 3 , name 4}
Similarly name 5 -> {name 6, name7} . So as per out example i have grouped by product and date. now what i'm trying to get it for a given name (which is c) map all its equivalent names. So grouping by c and want to collect all of them.

Comment: Adrian, if grouped by c again, it will become one to one mapping.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you want to have all values grouped by `a` and `b` and then populate this list as map with `c` as key.

You can achieve this by using [`Collectors.collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<MyObject>>>> myMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getA,
                Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getB,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                                l -> l.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getC, x -> l))
                        ))));
```

Using this list:

```
[
  {"a": "aaa", "b": "bbb", "c": "ccc", "d": "ddd", "e": "eee"},
  {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb",  "c": "cc",  "d": "ddd", "e": "ee" },
  {"a": "aa",  "b": "b",   "c": "ccc", "d": "d",   "e": "e"  },
  {"a": "aa",  "b": "b",   "c": "c",   "d": "dd",  "e": "ee" },
  {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb",  "c": "c",   "d": "dd",  "e": "eee"}
]
```

`myMap` would look like this:

```
{
  "aa": {
    "b": {
      "ccc": [
        {"a": "aa", "b": "b", "c": "ccc", "d": "d",   "e":  "e" },
        {"a": "aa", "b": "b", "c": "c",   "d" : "dd", "e" : "ee"}
      ],
      "c": [
        {"a": "aa", "b": "b", "c": "ccc", "d": "d",   "e":  "e" },
        {"a": "aa", "b": "b", "c": "c",   "d" : "dd", "e" : "ee"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aaa": {
    "bb": {
      "cc": [
        {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc", "d": "ddd", "e": "ee" }, 
        {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb", "c": "c",  "d": "dd",  "e": "eee"}
      ],
      "c": [
        {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc", "d": "ddd", "e": "ee" }, 
        {"a": "aaa", "b": "bb", "c": "c",  "d": "dd",  "e": "eee"}
      ]
    },
    "bbb": {
      "ccc": [
        {"a": "aaa", "b": "bbb", "c": "ccc", "d": "ddd", "e": "eee"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```